# Date to milliseconds in PHP

Tags: php, date

It maybe the simplest question but I'm struggling with this. I want to get the current time to millisecond for example `2016-03-04 11:57:00,00` without separators `2016030411570000`

I've tried this `date("YmdHisu")` but it returns time to microseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried this `date("YmdHisu")` but it returns time to microseconds.

If you don't need the microseconds then just strip them:

```
substr(date("YmdHisu"), 0, -3);
```

But, because currently [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) formats the value returned by [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) that doesn't contain fractions of seconds, the result will always end with `000` (no milliseconds available).

You can get the date and the milliseconds as you need if you use `date("YmdHis")` to format the date and time part (whole seconds) and extract and concatenate the first 3 digits of the microseconds part returned by [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php):

```
echo(date("YmdHis").substr(microtime(FALSE), 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
echo strtotime("2016-03-04 11:57:00") * 1000;
```

Output:

```
1457089020000
```

Comment: strtotime() * 1000 will express seconds as milliseconds.
I don't think it is possible to have millisecond precision with Date / Time in PHP. PHP functions based upon Unix Epoc only have a precision of 1000 milliseconds.


If don't really need a millisecond precision then forget this comment :-D

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$date = (new DateTime())->format('YmdHisv');
```

Comment: Copy-paste comments are probably not encouraged either. This answer doesn't need any further explanation and provides a shorter and easier way to do what OP asked for.

Comment: Atleast show the output what future readers can expect if they run this code..

Comment: The OP specified his desired output in the question. Did you read the question?

Comment: This answer needs php7 or later - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381248/is-there-a-php7-equivalent-to-the-c-net-datetime-now-tostringyyyymmddhhmmssff

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$dateTime = $date->format('YmdHisv');
```