# Is there a PHP7 equivalent to the C#.NET DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")?

Tags: c#, php-7

Considering this C#.NET code:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")
```

, is there any equivalent in PHP?

For the moment, I use the following:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
$formatted_timestamp = gmdate("YmdHms", $timestamp) . round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

However, it doesn't output the same results (from the seconds).

Comment: Did you try to read a manual of a function you're using?

Comment: You've got the month format ("m") in there twice.  "i" is for minutes.

Comment: Yes `"YmdHis"` The `m` is used for month, ___you already used it for Month___ so use `i` for minutes

Comment: See [the date documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for all of the format characters.

Comment: `date('YmdHisv')`

Comment: @RiggsFolly May I ask you why you put the question on hold? It raises a relevant feature in PHP, and it is actively being discussed. Explain? Thanks.

Comment: @steve Same question...

Comment: Because it is a question that could easily have been researched from the PHP manual and therefore offers no great benefit to be left on SO

Comment: @RiggsFolly I see. However, most questions on SO could have been researched from some manual :) Yet sometimes it is not totally obvious to everyone, and some help from someone who ran into the problem and did find while researching the manual, could help. SO is much better referenced than PHP manual. But -- I respect your choice. Thanks for answering. It just lacks some democracy :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using a `DateTime` object, you could simply format it:

```
$date = new DateTime();
return $date->format('YmdHisv');
```

the `'v'` is what you're looking for (milliseconds).

Caution: this requires PHP `7.1`, if you instantiate `DateTime()` with no arg, in order to obtain some non-0 milli (or micro) seconds.

Comment: I already tried this, but I get: `20190327165443000` (always 3 `0` at the end instead of actual ms) . With my method, I get something like: `201903271503361553702136609`.

Comment: @DVV Which version of PHP?

Comment: @DVV You need at least version `7.0.0` of php to use this as said [there](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php)

Comment: I know `v`is only available on PHP7, and it's my case

Comment: If it doesn't work, u can try `u` and split the resulting string by not taking the 3 last characters (microseconds) this is usable since `5.2.2`

Comment: @DVV You need `7.1`: Since you instanciate the DateTime object with no arguments, it takes the current Unix TS, which, before 7.1, was extracted only to the second. Look at the Changelog section in https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: yes that ^ you can try the `date(format)` function though

Comment: This works since `5.2.2`: `substr(date('YmdHisu'), 0, 17)`

Comment: @Nenri Does it? This is not explicit in the docs, as it says that `date()` defaults to using the timestamp that would be returned by `time()` (which is: seconds.)

Comment: @DVV "With my method, I get something like".  Which method?  With the PHP code posted in your question?  Or with your C# code?  The result of your PHP code isn't really relevant here since you say it is not what you want.  If that's the result of your C# code, then you're using a different format from what you say.